# Why object instantiation is not needed in some cases such as this?

Tags: java, object, memory-management, reference, instantiation

Why is it that sometimes we do not have to create an object and can just assign it to methods etc? Take the follow for instance.

```
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> list2 = Collections.synchronizedList(list1);
```

Does this mean that `list2` is assigned with an ArrayList object? What happens to the memory allocation in this case? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List2 is assigned with some implementation of the list. In the exact case it's either `SynchronizedRandomAccessList` object or `SynchronizedList` object, but not the `ArrayList`.

[Here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/Collections.java#Collections.synchronizedList%28java.util.List%29) is the source code:

```
public static <T> List<T> synchronizedList(List<T> list) {
        return (list instanceof RandomAccess ?
                new SynchronizedRandomAccessList<>(list) :
                new SynchronizedList<>(list));
}
```

The static method `synchronizedList()` is just a helper in this case. Objects in java (not primitive values) work on passing references to memory locations. So  `synchronizedList()` returns a memory reference to `new SynchronizedList()` object, and by calling it you assign that memory location to your `list2` object.

Answer (score 1):

Object instantiation is always needed. In Java there are two memory areas: the Thread Stack and the Heap.

- **Primitives** (i.e variables that are not objects) like  boolean, byte, short, char, int, long, float, double, are stored in the Thread Stack
- **Objects** that are created with the `new` keyword are allocated in the Heap

In your case the `List` object instantiated in the method `Collections.synchronizedList` will be allocated in the Heap and the reference to this list will be assigned to the local variable `list2`